# How to call injectable angular service from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular service in /src/app/services/myservice.ts as

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
constructor(@Inject(ACESS_TOKEN) private interface: IMyInterface, private http: HttpClient) {
}

getData(){
   return "Hello from Angular service";
}
```

And I have a javascript in /src/assests/viewer.js
I need to call `getData()` from viewer.js as:

```
var exam = {};
function setup(){
//call getData()
}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you run your viewer.js file? Do you include it in index.html or you add it in angular.json? And most importantly, when you call setup()?

Comment: I added viewer.js in angular.json and call from component's onclick function.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not -Angular transpile a minimify the .ts, so you can not be sure the name of the function-. You need think in other way. You can create a custom event in javascript (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and susbcribe in your service to this event